# Why is my Spring Boot entity ID generation failing?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, entity

I'm trying to auto-generate ID's for my entity, but it's not generating. Instead, it's starting from 1 when there already exists an entry with id "1" in my DB. Why is it not generating id "9" for my new entity?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically when creating a table with GenerationType.IDENTITY on postgres, Hibernate will setup the id column plus a *database sequence* to manage this id.

By convention the sequence name will be "*tablename*_id_seq".  E.g., for the table `ad_group_action` there will be a corresponding sequence `ad_group_action_id_seq`.  You can connect to the database to double-check the actual sequence name created.

The sequence just starts from 1 and increments each time a row is inserted by Hibernate.

But if there are pre-existing rows -- or if rows with existing IDs are inserted "manually" into the table -- those rows can conflict with the sequence.

One solution is to simply reset the sequence (from pgAdmin or another database client) to start at a higher number (say 100), using something like:

```sql
ALTER SEQUENCE ad_group_action_id_seq RESTART WITH 100;
```

Now Hibernate will not conflict with the existing rows (assuming their max id is < 100).

Alternatively, when inserting rows manually, omit the id column and let postgres automatically set them.  This way the table and the sequence will always be in sync.